# Exit Process started in Perl

Tags: perl, process, exit

Hi how would I be able to quit a process that has finished that was started using qx// in perl on a Linux machine?

I was thinking of calling ps to find the PID and call kill to exit. But I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You did `my $s = qx/some_command/;` in your Perl script and you want to manually kill `some_command` so that your script can get on with it?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do. I have a Java Jar I am calling and I want to exit it as soon as it is done processing.

Comment: But `qx//` returns as soon as the process exits and your jar should exit when it is finished. You shouldn't have to kill the `qx//` process unless it is stuck. What am I missing?

Comment: The process does not exit. I want to exit the Jar file when it is done processing and go back to my script. Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it but I'm not a Java guy. Maybe a bit of code in your question would clarify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
pkill -o -u urbanspr1nter -f some_command
```

or `pgrep ... | xargs ps` in place of `pkill` to review it first.

Comment: You can't run it from within the Perl script, since the script blocks until the process ends.  It will work if run from a shell, though.

Answer (score 4):

If it was launched with `qx//` and has finished, there's no need to kill it, it's already gone.  I suspect yours might actually be stuck: not finished process-wise, but not doing anything useful to you anymore.

There's nothing you can do directly from the Perl side of the operations.  `qx//` is a synchroneous call.  It expects the process it launches to terminate, and its only return code is the process's STDOUT dump.  (marginally, also its return code through `$?`)

It is not intended to spawn background processes.  As such, it gives you no access to the child's PID, let alone job control.

So in your case, if it's a one-shot problem, you'll just have to locate and terminate the faulty process through whatever combination of `ps`, `grep`, `kill`, `pgrep`, `pkill` suits your way of thinking best.  If it's a recurrent problem, you should migrate out of the builtin `qx//` facility to some that gives you better control.  For example, [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC%3a%3aRun) provides timeouts.

Answer (score 3):

I think the *real* question you want to ask is **"How do I start a process in the background (and possibly kill it later)?"**

The simplest solution is to [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) a pipe from the process.  So instead of

```
my $output = qx/some_command/;
# do something with $output
```

you'd do

```
my $pid = open my $pipe, "some_command |"  or die $!;
while (my $line = <$pipe>) {
    # do something with $line
    last if some_condition();
}
close $pipe  or $! and die $!;
```

If you [`close`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html) the pipe before the child process has terminated, the next time it tries to output something it will receive a SIGPIPE signal, which will normally kill it.  If you suspect that the process might keep running *without* producing any output, you can [`kill`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html) it manually with e.g.

```
kill $pid, 1;  # 1 == SIGHUP on most Unix systems
```

(You should do this *before* closing the pipe, since `close` will wait for the process to terminate.)

However, note that if Perl had to invoke a shell to parse your command, the process ID returned by `open` will be that of the shell, not of the actual command.  You can avoid this by using the multi-argument form of `open`:

```
my $pid = open my $pipe, '-|', $command, @command_args  or die $!;
```